# MySql: need SQL for selecting message by some rules

Tags: mysql, except

I have three tables and need to get messages where user PETER IS NOT sender AND IS NOT recipient.

Table 'messages'

```
idMessage  | bodyText          | idUserSender
---------------------------------------------
1          | This is message 1 | 2
2          | This is message 2 | 1
3          | This is message 3 | 1
```

Table 'users'

```
idUser     | name
-------------------
1          | John
2          | Peter
3          | Marco
```

Table 'messageRecipients'

```
idMessage  | idUserRecipient
----------------------------
1          | 1
1          | 3
2          | 1
2          | 3
3          | 2
3          | 3
```

So the resultset should be:

```
idMessage  | bodyText          | idUserSender
---------------------------------------------
2          | This is message 2 | 1
```

I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM messages AS M
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUser <> 2
) AS allUsersWithoutPeter ON M.idUserSender = allUsersWithoutPeter.idUser
GROUP BY M.idMessage
```

and got messages where Peter is not sender, but don't know how to except messages where Peter is recipient too and get only messages where Peter is not included anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.* FROM Messages m
JOIN messageRecipients r ON
r.idMessage = m.idMessage
    AND r.idUserRecipient <> 2
WHERE m.idUserSender <> 2
```

You could, of course parameterise this query to exclude any `idUser`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  m.*
from
  messages m
join
  users u on u.idUser != m.idUserSender and u.name='Peter'
join
  messageRecipients mr on mr.idMessage = m.idMessage and mr.idUserRecipient != u.idUser
```